# How to prove $\lim_{x\to0}\sin x\log x = 0$

Tags: limits

How to prove $\lim_{x\to0}\sin x\log x = 0$

My try:

I tried using expansions of sin and log but that does not seem to work.

Comment: Try
$$
  \sin x \log x = \frac{\sin x}{x} x \log x.
$$
:-)

Comment: Do you mean $\sin(x\log x)$ or $(\sin x)(\log x)$?

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini Second one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can't use any taylor expansion for $\log(x)$

But you can say that $\sin x \sim x$, then you have $$\lim_{x \to 0} x\log x = 0$$

Because $x$ goes to $0$ so much faster than $\log x$ goes to infinity.

Or if you have to justify that,  rewrite the limit as

$$\frac{\log(x)}{\frac{1}{x}}$$ then use l'Hopital

Comment: Or with $x=e^{-y}$: $\lim_{y\to\infty} \frac{-y}{e^y}$

Comment: But notice that if you know that $f\sim g$, it is not true that you can always substitute $g$ to $f$ in a limit.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini well when you have products it is true. My rule of thumb is that if you substitute and some terms cancel out leaving $0$, then it's wrong and you have to use taylor approximation of higher order :)

Answer (score 2):

You must know the following fundamentals:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1,\qquad
\lim_{x \to 0} x^\alpha \log x = 0.
$$

Answer (score 2):

you can use L'Hopital twice
$$\lim_{x\to0}\sin x\log x =\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log x}{\csc x} 
\\=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{1}{ x}}{-\csc x\cot x}
\\=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^2x}{ x\cos x}
\\= \lim_{x\to0}\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{ -x\sin x+\cos x}=0$$

Answer (score -1):

lim x tends to 0 log sin x/1/x
=Limx tends to 0cosx/sinx/1/x^(-2)
=limx tends to 0 cotx/-1/x^2
=Limx tends to 0 -x^2/tanx
=Limx tends to 0 -2x/sec^2x
=0